# Why am I not able to access values that were stored in another function?

Tags: c, arrays, function, pointers

Basically, why does it not just print the integers that are entered.  Right now it just prints garbage value, but I do not know why it cannot access the values stored after it leaves the function. It only seems to get messed up after leaving the getIntegersFromUser function. If I run the for loop in the getIntegers function it does it properly, but why not in the main function?

Thanks in advance for your help.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void getIntegersFromUser(int N, int *userAnswers)
{
    int i;
    userAnswers =(int *)malloc(N*sizeof(int));
    if (userAnswers)
        { printf("Please enter %d integers\n", N);
          for (i=0;i<N; i++)
            scanf("%d", (userAnswers+i));
        }
}
int main()
{
    int i, M=5;
    int *p;
    getIntegersFromUser(M, p);
    for (i=0;i<5;i++)
        printf ("%d\n", p[i]);

    return 0;
}
```

Also, this is a homework question, but it's a "Bonus Question", so I'm not trying to "cheat" I just want to make sure I understand all the course material, but if you could still try to give a fairly thorough explanation so that I can actually learn the stuff that would be awesome.

Comment: Hint: *finish what you start*. If you have `malloc`, you should also have `free`. In most cases, it is strongly advisable to have `malloc` and `free` in the same function. And of course you shouldn't access memory after you called `free` on it. With this hint, you might find a way how to fix your problem with the pointer being passed by value in an elegant way.

Comment: Note that function arguments are LOCAL variables.

Answer (score 0):

Pointers are passed by value.  The function is using a copy of your pointer, which is discarded when the function ends.  The caller never sees this copy.

To fix it, you could return the pointer.

```
int *getIntegersFromUser(int N)
{
    int *userAnswers = malloc(...);
    ...
    return userAnswers;
}

/* caller: */
int *p = getIntegersFromUser(M);
```

Or you could pass your pointer by reference so the function is acting on the same pointer, not a copy.

```
void getIntegersFromUser(int N, int **userAnswers)
{
    *userAnswers = (int *) malloc(N*sizeof(int));
    ...
}

/* caller: */
int *p;
getIntegersFromUser(N, &p);
```

Comment: Both are still bad style. The function performs the allocation and leaves it to the caller which can only marvel at how do perform deallocation (especially when the content of the array is something other than a primitive type). Accept a pointer to an array and its size as arguments. Leave allocation to the callee.